Arduino code and data logger shield - when to open and close log file?
Below is code for an arduino uno with the adafruit data logger sheild. I want to dynamically set a filename in setup() and then write to the file in loop(). I am struggling to figure out where to initialize the filename, and when to SD.open() and logfile.close(). Any advice would be appreciated. This code works through setup() but hits the "Failed to open file" once it begins the loop.
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include "TFMini.h"
#include "RTClib.h"
#include "SD.h"
#include <Wire.h>

#define LOG_INTERVAL  500 // milliseconds between sensor readings
#define ECHO_TO_SERIAL   1 // echo data to serial port
#define WAIT_TO_START    0 // Wait for serial input in setup()

// Setup software serial port 
SoftwareSerial Serial1(2,3); //define software serial port name as Serial1 and define pin2 as RX and pin3 as TX
TFMini tfmini;

const int buttonPin = 4; // the pin to which the pushbutton is attached

// DATA LOGGER
RTC_PCF8523 RTC; // define the Real Time Clock object
char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
const int chipSelect = 10; // for the data logging shield, we use digital pin 10 for the SD cs line
File logfile; // the logging file

// variables will change:
boolean buttonState = 0;         // current state of the button
boolean lastButtonState = 0;     // previous state of the button

char filename[] = "LOGGER00.CSV"; // declare filename globally so it can be dynamically set in setup() and accessed in loop()


void error(char *str)
// prints out the error to the Serial Monitor, turns on the red error LED
// and then sits in a while(1); loop forever, also known as a halt
{
  Serial.print("error: ");
  Serial.println(str);
  
  // red LED indicates error
  // digitalWrite(redLEDpin, HIGH);
  
  while(1);
}

void setup() 
{
  // Step 1: Initialize hardware serial port (serial debug port)
  Serial.begin(9600); //set bit rate of serial port connecting Arduino with computer
  while (!Serial); // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only                                                                
  
  Serial.println ("Initializing TF03 LiDAR...");

  // Step 2: Initialize the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port (set bit rate of serial port connecting LiDAR with Arduino)
  Serial1.begin(TFMINI_BAUDRATE);

  // Step 3: Initialize the TF Mini sensor
  tfmini.begin(&Serial1);
  delay(100);

  // Initialize the button pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); 

  #if WAIT_TO_START
    Serial.println("Type any character to start");
    while (!Serial.available());
  #endif //WAIT_TO_START

  // Initialize the SD card
  Serial.print("\nInitializing SD card...");
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT); // make sure that the default chip select pin is set to output, even if you don't use it

  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    // don't do anything more:
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("card initialized.");
  
  // determine next file name
  // char filename[] = "LOGGER00.CSV";
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    filename[6] = i/10 + '0';
    filename[7] = i%10 + '0';
    if (! SD.exists(filename)) {
      break;  // leave the loop!
    }
  }

  // logfile = SD.open(nextfile, FILE_WRITE); 
  // Open the file with the determined filename
  logfile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);
  if (! logfile) {
    error("couldnt create file");
  }
  
  Serial.print("Logging to: ");
  Serial.println(filename);

  // kick off the RTC by initializing the Wire library and poking the RTC to see if its alive.
  Wire.begin();  
  if (!RTC.begin()) {
    logfile.println("RTC failed");
#if ECHO_TO_SERIAL
    Serial.println("RTC failed");
#endif  //ECHO_TO_SERIAL
  }

  Serial.print("Writing to test.txt...");
  logfile.println("millis,stamp,datetime,distance,strength,buttonState");    
#if ECHO_TO_SERIAL
  Serial.println("millis,stamp,datetime,distance,strength,buttonState");
#endif
  logfile.close(); //include?????
  Serial.println("done.");
}

void loop() 
{

  DateTime now; 

  // delay for the amount of time we want between readings
  delay((LOG_INTERVAL -1) - (millis() % LOG_INTERVAL));

  logfile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE); // include this?????
  if (!logfile) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file");
    return;
  }

  // log milliseconds since starting
  uint32_t m = millis();
  logfile.print(m);           // milliseconds since start
  logfile.print(", ");    
#if ECHO_TO_SERIAL
  Serial.print("Milliseconds since start: ");
  Serial.print(m); 
  Serial.println();
#endif

  // fetch the time
  now = RTC.now();
  // log time
  logfile.println(now.unixtime()); // seconds since 1/1/1970
  logfile.print(", ");
  logfile.print('"');
  logfile.print(now.year(), DEC);
  logfile.print("/");
  logfile.print(now.month(), DEC);
  logfile.print("/");
  logfile.print(now.day(), DEC);
  logfile.print(" ");
  logfile.print(now.hour(), DEC);
  logfile.print(":");
  logfile.print(now.minute(), DEC);
  logfile.print(":");
  logfile.print(now.second(), DEC);
  logfile.print('"');
#if ECHO_TO_SERIAL
  Serial.print("Unixtime: ");
  Serial.print(now.unixtime()); // seconds since 1/1/1970
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Datetime: ");
  Serial.print('"');
  Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
  Serial.print('"');
  Serial.println();
#endif //ECHO_TO_SERIAL

  // Take one TF Mini distance measurement
  uint16_t dist = tfmini.getDistance();
  uint16_t strength = tfmini.getRecentSignalStrength();

  // log ditance and signal strength
  logfile.print(", ");    
  logfile.print(dist); // cm
  logfile.print(", ");    
  logfile.print(strength);
#if ECHO_TO_SERIAL
  Serial.print("Distance (cm): ");
  Serial.print(dist); 
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Signal Strength: ");
  Serial.print(strength); 
  Serial.println();
#endif //ECHO_TO_SERIAL

  // read the pushbutton input pin:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  // log button state
  logfile.print(", ");    
  logfile.print(buttonState);
#if ECHO_TO_SERIAL
  Serial.print("Button state: ");
  Serial.print(buttonState); 
  Serial.println();
#endif //ECHO_TO_SERIAL

  logfile.close(); // include this???
}


